# How to get MSBUILD to precompile .aspx pages

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, teamcity

I am working to setup a build server using Team City to build and deploy asp.net web applications to a staging site with transformed web.configs automatically. Everything is working except that the code that ends up on the website (the aspx files) have the HTML in them when you open them in notepad.

Before all of this I was using web deployment projects with websites, and the code was compiled. If you opened one after it was deployed, it said it was a marker file.

I have tried some tutorials on how this process should work, but the code always ends up in an editable state (the html).

My question is:

What do I need to do to get MSBUILD from the command line to ultimately have precompiled code on the webs server?

Any suggestions, links, pointers, or ideas would be very helpful to me.

Comment: You should just be able to set the MvcBuildViews property in your project file to true.

Answer (score 1):

You need to invoke the [aspnet_compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) tool to do this.  There are some limitations or complications depending on exactly what you need to do for things like strong-naming.  The MSDN article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) has pointers.

I used to have MSBuild project steps that did this, but we decided to drop precompiling because our clients want to integrate our product into their internal portals, and precompiling made things complicated for them.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MS Web Deploy? I use it regularly for automated deployments from my Team City Build server to dev, staging, QA, etc. And I'm transforming configurations as well.

If you want to check out this alternative you can follow the excellent guide by Troy Hunt:
http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/you-deploying-it-wrong-teamcity_26.html

Comment: I am using msbuild via the command line in Team City to build, and then robo copy with power shell in Team City to deploy.I have learned since I posted my original question that I need to use msdeploy to copy my code to the server, in this case I am trying to get it to my staging server. Thanks for the article, I have only made it about half way through it as of right now.

Comment: It'll probably be simpler letting MS Deploy do that for you, yes. And it has different ways to automate the transformations of your config files. Troy's guide was a great start for me. I hope it helps you as well.